# Global existence for one Cauchy problem based on global existence of other two auxiliary Cauchy problems

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, existence-theorems, cauchy-problem

I have a Cauchy problem for the differential equation
\begin{equation}
y' = f(t, y),
\end{equation}
with initial condition $y(0) = y^0$; here, $y$ and $f$ are two-dimensional vector-functions. The function $f$ is smooth with respect to $(t, y) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^2$. So, in accordance with classical results, the solution to this problem exists and is unique in some vicinity of $t = 0$.

I also have auxiliary Cauchy problems for differential equations
\begin{equation}
u' = U(u),
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
u' = -U(u),
\end{equation}
with initial conditions $u(0) = u^0$ and $u(0) = u_0$, respectively; here, $u$ and $U$ are scalar (one-dimensional) functions and $U(u)$ is continuous with respect to $u \in \mathbb R$. Besides this, $U(u) \geqslant 0$ for $u \in \mathbb R$ and it is true that
$$
|y'(t)| = |f(t, y)| \leqslant U(|y(t)|)
$$
(that's why these Cauchy problems are called "auxiliary" for the original one).

Let $u^0 (t)$ and $u_0 (t)$ be solutions of the auxiliary Cauchy problems; it is supposed that they both exist on the segment $[0, \theta]$.

Finally, the following estimate
\begin{equation}
u_0 (t) \leqslant |y(t)| \leqslant u^0(t),
\end{equation}
is given, where $y(t)$ is the solution to the first (two-dimensional) Cauchy problem and $|\cdot|$ is the euclidean norm, i.e. $|y(t)| = \sqrt{y_1^2 + y_2^2}$.

So, I am interested if there is any theorem guaranteeing that my original problem has a solution defined on the same segment where $u^0 (t)$ and $u_0 (t)$ exist (that is $[0, \theta]$) and that on this segment the estimate mentioned above is true.

Comment: Is there any relationship at all between $u_0$, $u^0$, and $y_0$? Also, any relationship between $f$ and $U$? As it stands I don't see how there can be any theorem that does what you want.

Comment: Where (for what $t$) does the estimate $u_0(t)\leq |y(t)|\leq u^0(t)$ holds?

Comment: "so (...) the solution to this problem exists and is *unique* ". It is not unique, in general, with just continuous $f$.

Comment: @WillieWong, sorry for missing that in my question. I added some additional details to my question.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, this estimate holds on the interval where all these functions exist. It is known that $u_0(t)$ and $u^0 (t)$ exist at least on the segment $[0, \theta]$ and, as for $y(t)$, it is known that it exists in some vicinity of $0$. So, the estimate holds at least in some vicinity of $0$. I want to prove that $y(t)$ exists for $t \in [0, \theta]$ and that the estimate mentioned holds for $t \in [0, \theta]$.

Comment: @PietroMajer, no doubt) I was inaccurate in asking my question. The function $f(t, y)$ is smooth. I've fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: For which $t$ does the inequality $|f(t,y)| < U(|y(t)|)$ hold? For that to hold it seems to presuppose that the solution $y(t)$ exists. So given a system for which I know that $y(t)$ exists (and is bounded) on some interval $[-t_0, t_0]$ and blows up at $t \gg t_0$, what's to stop me to just choose $U$ to be some constant bigger than $\sup |f(t, y(t))|$ on that time interval, and $u_0$ and $u^0$ some linear functions that bound $|y(t)|$ on $[-t_0, t_0]$, and call it a day?

Comment: @WillieWong, I got what you meant. Indeed, classical results work properly here and nothing else is required in this case. Thanks for your help.